# Google Chrome selects whole column if I want to select a row

Tags: css, google-chrome, selection

Whenever I try to select a row (username + message), Google Chrome select the entire column.
If I press CTRL+C (CMD+C) and CTRL+V (CMD+V), only the row -just as expected- is copied/inserted.

[image]

It works fine on Firefox, Safari and Opera:
[image]

You can view a life-example by visiting [**Metahill**](http://www.metahill.com) and joining as **[Guest](http://www.metahill.com)**.

**How do I fix this in Chrome? It should look like it does in all the other browsers.**

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: How to fix it in chrome?

Comment: @poitroae can you provide a cut-down example (say in a jsfiddle) that exhibits the same behaviour?

Comment: @David-SkyMesh http://jsfiddle.net/KgKYs/

Comment: I can confirm the issue in Chrome 23.0.1271.95 on Linux 64 bit.

Comment: Why are you using `<div>`s instead of a `<table>` here?

Comment: When I play around with the `float` CSS properites, I no longer get that behaviour (but obviously it doesn't look correct).

Comment: I agree with Bill. A table layout may fix the selection problem. You should give it a try. You also probably should file a bug report.

Comment: I'm not sure what the *expected* selection behaviour should be under relevant standards, but it *seems* like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Chrome 31, it works like a charm again :).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `table` here. It'll get around this problem and it's more semantic.

```
<tr>
  <td class="time">2:27</td>
  <td class="nick">Bob</td>
  <td class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</td>
</tr>
```

Here's a quick little demo I mocked up.

http://jsbin.com/EXaZAK/1/edit

Comment: But really, this is just layout. Is there anything about this data that's inately "tabular" ?

Comment: I guess it depends on the definition of tabular? I thought it was pretty obvious. We could put in table headers to label the three columns which are time, nick and message. You can copy and paste this table right into a spreadsheet program and it'll be clearly formatted. Not sure what else there is to it.

Comment: I mean from a 'separation of data and presentation' perspective. Is this data really tabular? If you encountered it printed in a book (or read aloud by a screen reader) would you expect it to be tabular?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with how they read tabular data to know exactly. I wouldn't expect a calendar to be read tabular but that's how they're typically marked up. I think this is a good use of one though!

Comment: And all I'm saying is that since the 'semantic web' and Web2 was a thing, that it's not for granted that they *should* be marked up as tables (as opposed to the *layout* of a table). As for whether CSS3 fills the gaps adequately with alternate layout modules --- that's another question. For example, in compliant browsers, you can use an assortment of `display: table-*` properties to display *any* elements with table-like behaviours.

Comment: I'm picking up what you're putting down.

Comment: I am not sure if that is really better. Maybe a bit, but it is not an ultimate solution. :/ https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6559846/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-17%20at%204.36.22%20PM.png